# How to get key's names returning after Twitter Success?

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am a newbee in `java`. I have integrated *Twitter* with the help of *Fabric SDK*. 
I am getting data like screen_name,username etc. as mentioned in a tutorial. But I am unable to get the tweets. 
**I didn't know the Exact key name for that**. When I am print the data returned after success All I see is an ID with `models.User`. This is confusing me. 
*MainActivity.java*

```
 loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

            Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                    .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {

                        @Override
                        public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

                            User user = userResult.data;
                          System.out.println(user);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                        }

                    });

            loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

        }
    });
```

*Console*

```
I/System.out: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User@427ba968
```

Hope that someone solve this.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this

```
@Override
public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

User user = userResult.data;
System.out.println(user);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String userFeed = gson.toJson(user);
System.out.println(userFeed);
}
```

this `gson` gave json data from models.User.